# How to move all connections connected to an endpoint at once?

Tags: jsplumb

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vt21.png)

Is it possible to drag multiple connections at the same time?

See image, Node 1 and 2 are connected to Node 3. Is it possible to move that connection with one drag in jsPlumb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently possible but it is an interesting idea. It's been opened as a ticket on the Github repository:

https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb/issues/1066